# How to activate mobile native share in a website?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, web, plugins

I wanted to have a share button like this on my site: 
[image: Share Button]

That when clicked will open up this the mobile OS's sharing function:
(example is from a Xiao Mi Mi 4i phone)
[image]

or

[image]
Is there any method to induced the Send bar below by a website link?

Answer (score -1):

To enable the Web Share API you need:

Sign up to get the trial token.
During the next 24 hours, you are sent an email with the Trial Token and details how to include it to the Web App.
You include the token via header or directly into the page HTML, globally or everywhere where you want to use the API:

```
<meta http-equiv="origin-trial" data-feature="Web Share" content="TOKEN_FROM_THE_EMAIL">
```

Web Share trial was introduced in Chrome 55 and may end in April 2017, after which may be enabled by default in the browser.

Let’s summarize the steps to make the Web Share API work:

The site is served via HTTPS.
The origin trial header/meta is provided till the API enabled by default
`navigator.share()` is called via user action (click, tap..)

Please find the below mentioned URL

https://blog.hospodarets.com/web-share-api